# What is the argument position of a noun in vocative case in a sentence?

Tags: syntax, cases, nouns

What is the argument position (e.g. subject, direct object, ...) of a noun in vocative case  in a sentence, for example, in Latin?

Comment: In what language? I can think of how some languages that have a vocative case would handle this, but that doesn't necessarily extend to all of them.

Comment: Normally it's an appositive in Latin, like _Et tu, Brute?_ I don't know what the Latin grammarians called it, but their syntax was as nonexistent as their phonology, so it hardly matters. As for argument position, anything in the vocative (which can't be distinguished from the accusative except in 2nd decl masc (like _Brute_) is not an argument in any clause; like ablative and genitive, it doesn't mark a grammatical relation. Nominative, accusative, and dative mark 1, 2, and 3, respectively.  Except when they're idiomatic, which is frequently.